# How to send data without reloading page with cURL?

Tags: php, curl, post, get

I am trying log in a website which has security code for 2 days like you see below. 
[image]

(By the way, I can get security number from html codes of web page.)

First, I have to connect to website and get the code(254), than post username, password and security number. But there is a big problem. I am getting security number **and the page is reloading and the code is changing everytime when I try post to webpage this variables.**

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php


    include('simple_html_dom.php'); 


    $url = "http://example.com/index.php";

    $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";

    $tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies.txt';

    $ch = curl_init();   // GET REQUEST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
        $str = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $str; 
        curl_close($ch);

        preg_match('~<td><img src="number/(.*?).jpg"></td>~', $str, $securityNo); // I am gettin security number



    echo $securityNo[1]; // It print true

    $username = "USER";
    $password = "PASS";



    $postfields = array();
    $postfields['UserName'] =$username; // Username
    $postfields['Password'] = $password; // Password
    $postfields['code'] = $securityNo[1]; // Code
    $postfields['LOGIN'] = "LOGIN"; // BUTTON
    $curl =curl_init();

             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

        $ret = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    echo $ret;

    ?>
```

I printed screen both *'echo $str'* (get request) and *'echo $ret'* (post request) but there is different 2 codes in screen, not same code printed.

I researched on internet too much, but I got nothing. I can't solve this. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So that number changes every time you reload the form? A site using such measures in all likelihood does not _want_ you to login using any such automated measures.

Comment: Yeah, the number between 0 and 1000, I know that. But it changed every reload.

Comment: Post the real url (as a comment), so we can test it, you can remove it after.

Comment: _"But it changed every reload"_ - well that's the point ... to make it harder for you to achieve what you are trying to do here (which again, the site does not seem to _want_, because otherwise they would probably not be using this measure.) So you would need to request the URL the form is on first, extract the number from it, and then send the necessary cookies/tokens with the next request, to keep the session on the remote site alive.

Comment: need to know how the browser logs in before we can be of much help. what does the Network tab of the dev tools of your browser say about post arguments when logging in? (in chrome, its F12 -> Network tab, make sure to press "Preserve Log" before you log in)

Comment: I noticed my code doesn't make POST request, only make get request, Google Dev tools network tab says this. But why localhost doesn't make post request? Any idea?